# Not able to make agent node online in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh, private-key, public-key, jenkins-agent

[image]

```
SSHLauncher{host='10.10.0.15', port=22, credentialsId='veera', jvmOptions='', javaPath='', prefixStartSlaveCmd='', suffixStartSlaveCmd='', launchTimeoutSeconds=210, maxNumRetries=10, retryWaitTime=15, sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy=hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.KnownHostsFileKeyVerificationStrategy, tcpNoDelay=true, trackCredentials=true}
[06/30/20 13:12:15] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 10.10.0.15:22.
[06/30/20 13:12:15] [SSH] SSH host key matches key in Known Hosts file. Connection will be allowed.
ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for veera-jenkins (credentialId:veera/method:publickey)
ERROR: Failed to authenticate as veera-jenkins with credential=veera
java.io.IOException: Publickey authentication failed.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.authenticatePublicKey(AuthenticationManager.java:302)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.authenticateWithPublicKey(Connection.java:451)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.TrileadSSHPublicKeyAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(TrileadSSHPublicKeyAuthenticator.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHAuthenticator.authenticate(SSHAuthenticator.java:436)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHAuthenticator.authenticate(SSHAuthenticator.java:473)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:861)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$1.call(SSHLauncher.java:425)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$1.call(SSHLauncher.java:412)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: PEM problem: it is of unknown type
    at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.PEMDecoder.decodeKeyPair(PEMDecoder.java:500)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.authenticatePublicKey(AuthenticationManager.java:236)
```

Comment: I'd suggest you first  review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Hint: It generally involves asking an actual question, describing the issue, formatting code/output, labeling screenshots (not having screenshots of text), and so on. This is not an actual HelpDesk, rather people helping people. Did you Google "PEM problem: it is of unknown type"? Did you review [JENKINS-53954](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53954)? Are you sure the credentials "veera-jenkins with credential=veera" are correct?

Comment: I've improved the error formatting and shown the image, but the question is still not clear, and making it clear is up to you.

Comment: I am not able to make slave node in jenkins online after doing all the above configuration which is shared in screenshot